# Old laptop turns off due to overheating

Tags: windows, laptop, software-rec, overheating

I have an old laptop that powers off when the processor's temperature exceeds 84 °C. The more annoying part is Flash causes this most of the time. If I watch a web feed for more than 15-20 minutes, it results in a hard shutdown of the machine.

I have an idea of a could-be solution to this problem: I want a program that would decrease the processor's clock speed to about 1.2 GHz (or whatever) if the processor exceeds the temperature of 82 °C, thus leading it a lower temperature.

Is there a program out there that does this?

The laptop is a Dell Inspiron 1501, with an AMD Turion 64 X2 TL-50, integrated graphics (x1150) and 2.5 GB of DDR2 RAM.

CPU-Z screenshot:
[image]

Comment: Have you tried cleaning the dust out? Even a good hoover can make a difference (make sure you jam the fans with a paperclip first)

Comment: Yeah, I clean it at regular intervals. @MilesHayler

Comment: Fair enough. In that case what laptop is it? Make/model. What CPU? What chipset?

Comment: @MilesHayler, edited my queston.

Comment: could you find out the specific CPU? You can download CPU-Z for this

Comment: I assume this didn't used to happen.  Try to figure out what's changed.

Comment: Done. :) @MilesHayler

Comment: Yes, when the laptop was new, it didn't used to happen, but after 2years or so, something went wrong, took it to a technician, he solved it. He said, all that was wrong was an IC got burnt down. For a month the laptop ran smooth, then the the problem arised again, and I was like, "To hell with it!". :( @DanielRHicks

Comment: What version of Windows are you running? In Vista and 7 you can go to Power Options -> Advanced settings, and under "Processor power management", set "System cooling policy" to "Passive", which will try to lower the clock speed to cool the CPU ("Active" will try to increase fan speed instead).

Comment: @Indrek, thanks for the edit. And ok, let me try that and I'll come back to you if it helps or if it doesn't. :)

Comment: and I'm using Windows 7 Ultimate 64bit. @Indrek

Comment: "all that was wrong was an IC got burnt down" is a strange turn of phrase.  If an IC burned up that wasn't such a casual problem, and I'd be surprised that the unit was repairable.  I'm wondering if maybe he found a heat sink loose and reinstalled it.  And maybe it's come loose again.

Comment: I didn't got into any details, you know, he showed me the burnt IC that he said he had changed. At that point of time, I didn't had knowledge that it could be an overheating issue, if I had acknowledged that, I would've surely given him specifics he should take care. And if you ask me, it is casual for a technician to change if an IC gets burnt down, computer repair services are more than you're estimating/perceiving them to be. And it just costed me about $30, surprised? @DanielRHicks

Comment: I'd say you were snookered somehow.  First off "burnt down" is not a term I'm familiar with in computer service lingo.  Second, you can't replace an IC for $30 unless it's socketed, and only expensive ICs are socketed.  Most service places will charge you $100 or so to just open the lid.

Comment: I won't neglect it as a possibility that I was snookered. Burnt down is a term just used by me, because I was aware the laptop turns hot often, I could not decline the possibility that the soldering of an IC or the IC itself got effected by the temperature conditions. In the technicians case, I would say, his exact words were like, "I have changed this part".

Comment: And when he showed me the condition of the part that was changed, anyone could easily guess, that the IC was burnt and damaged. Not like the IC got melted like wax, but it was broke in two pieces(or more? i don't remember) and one could see the damage that the temperature has caused it. But if, it was all a sham, from his side, and he just wanted my money, he did fix something in the laptop though, that made it ran in the correct manner for the following 1 month or so. Coming to the price price part, maybe you are right, but the IC wasn't socketed. @DanielRHicks

Comment: "Most service places will charge you $100 or so to just open the lid." In your area maybe, but I was at a marketplace that specifically deals with broken computers(or computer stuff), the competition is so much that the prices are low. I could give you more info about the marketplace, if only I was not concerned about privacy. But to give you a mental picture of the marketplace's vastness, nearly 20,000+ deals are done everyday in that area alone, and this is just a figure that I could imagine looking at the general population that comes and goes to the market just to pick a good deal.

Comment: The figure is definitely the minimum estimation of mine, and I don't have any idea of what maximum figure could be. @DanielRHicks

Comment: Easy for the guy to blow the dust out, reseat a few connectors, show you a burned part, and tell you that was the problem.

Answer (score 4):

[RealTemp](http://www.techpowerup.com/realtemp/) lets you adjust the **Clock Modulation** by percentage of the maximum, but that's only an ugly patch for the underlying problem.

The most common causes of overheating laptops are (more or less in that order):

- The CPU cooler's exhaust vents are clogged up with dust.

  This normally causes the temperature of all other components to raise as well.
- Dirty or malfunctioning CPU fan.
- The CPU cooler needs to be reseated.

Comment: +1 for CPU cooler.  If dust is not an issue, check the screws retaining the CVPU cooler. I often find the screws work loose due to constant heat/cool cycle and a quick tighten is needed.  Unusual not to find this on laptops.

Comment: `The Processor detected is not supported. Amd Turion 64x2 Mobile Techonology TL-50` :(

Answer (score 0):

There may be settings in the BIOS that will allow you to control the processor speed.  In a previous Dell laptop I had, you could either allow it full control or force it to a minimum, so that may not be what you're looking for.

82 degrees is really hot.  I would suggest getting an external cooler, such as [this](http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16834999850) or [this](http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16834992853).  I have both of these.  The latter is larger, lighter and quieter, but it's not as forgiving of rough handling or balancing the laptop on one knee (causes the fan to scrape).  Both of these work very well for keeping my laptop running cool under almost any circumstance.

Another option is to install a fan control program and force your fans to spin fast earlier than the motherboard does on it's own.  My preferred program is [SpeedFan](http://www.almico.com/sfdownload.php), but it has a tendency to not work on Inspirons.  If you're not running 64 bit windows, then there is an Inspiron-specific alternative here.  Both of these can be set to turn on fans at specific temperatures, or you use them to just force the fans to high all the time.

Answer (score 0):

I would also suggest you to buy a laptop cooler and maybe enhance your laptop case and cooler a bit.  I have a similar problem and it helped a bit when also I have a hole in my laptop case for a better airflow. When you want to play with software you can check the windows energy saver or power management policy and use a fan control program like speedfan or nhc laptop control. You can also try to enable additional energy saving and undervolt your cpu with turion power control.  Maybe you also suffer from the problem that the fan doesn't run at full speed when the cpu is maxed out? Then you need a fan control program like speedfan or a more recent version of windows.

Answer (score 0):

I believe RMClock should be able to adjust your CPU clocks. Give it a try and let us know.

http://cpu.rightmark.org/products/rmclock.shtml

Comment: Windows 7 needs signed driver, apparently RMClock was abandoned and was never updated for Windows 7. But you suggested in the right direction, I'll +1 you as soon as I reach a rep of 15. :)